# .HTACCESS Tricks - Rewriting for dynamic content

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to be able to make it so that when someone visits my site at say:

**a) http://www.mysite.com/article/this-article/**

It actually displays the content from:

**b) http://www.mysite.com/article/index.php?src=this-article**

and also if a user types in (b) then they are 301'd to (a)

In my HT access I currently have the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on


# index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# force www.
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*\;.*\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're describing is possible using only rewrite rules. But you can use a combination of rewrite rules and PHP like so:

Change your .htaccess file to look like this (NOTE: This is assuming your .htaccess file is in your root)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  # force www.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/article/index(-new)?\.php
  # this is looking for anything past article that is not a /. You may 
  # need to change that to be more inclusive - something like (.*)
  RewriteRule ^article/([^\/]+) /article/index-new.php?src=$1 [L,NC]

  # index.php to /
  RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html)$ / [R=301,L]
  #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP
  #RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*\;.*\ HTTP/
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
  RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Your article/index.php will become a redirector to your new index.php, and would look something like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["src"]))
        header("location: /article/" . basename($_GET["src"])); // Using basename() in case src happens to be referring to an actual file in your code
    else
        header("location: /");
?>
```

Your "real" index would actually be index-new.php, which is what the rewrite rule would be calling.